# How is Adobe Update Notifier auto launched on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, login, adobe, automation

It seems the Adobe Update Notifier sometime autolaunches on startup, however I cannot find where it's launched from. I've checked in Lingon as well as my login startup items but it's not there.

Any idea where else it could be? The full process is:

> /Applications/Utilities/Adobe Application Manager/UWA/AAM Updates Notifier.app/Contents/MacOS/AAM Updates Notifier -psn_0_127007

Comment: Sorry, I had not enough reputation for the comment.
File names on my machine were: > com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist com.adobe.CS5ServiceManager.plist > com.adobe.AdobeCreativeCloud.plis

Comment: What are these files as you do not seem to be the person who asked the question?

Comment: @Mark, Adobe uses various file names for their daemons, sometime they start with "AAM", sometime "ARM", sometime ends with "Updater-1.0", sometime "Scheduler-1.0", etc. So I guess it's useful to know about the various names.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The updater is registered with the system service `launchd`. Instructions to completely disable this can be found on [The real way to disable Adobe Updater from your Mac OS X](http://lifecs.likai.org/2011/02/real-way-to-disable-adobe-updater-from.html):

Open a Terminal window and type the following commands:

```
cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl remove `basename com.adobe.ARM.* .plist`
launchctl remove `basename com.adobe.AAM.* .plist`
launchctl remove com.adobe.ARM.Scheduler-1.0
launchctl remove com.adobe.AAM.Scheduler-1.0
rm com.adobe.ARM.*
rm com.adobe.AAM.*
```

Note that depending on your version of Adobe programs, some of the above lines may generate errors. That's fine.

If the above does not disable it, you may need to remove it at a system level. You'd use the same commands as above, but with two additions/changes:

```
sudo -s
[type your administrator password when prompted]
cd /Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl remove `basename com.adobe.ARM.* .plist`
launchctl remove `basename com.adobe.AAM.* .plist`
launchctl remove com.adobe.ARM.Scheduler-1.0
launchctl remove com.adobe.AAM.Scheduler-1.0
rm com.adobe.ARM.*
rm com.adobe.AAM.*
exit
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I couldn't get it to work following exactly this method but, in my case, this worked: `launchctl remove "com.adobe.AAM.Scheduler-1.0"` then `rm com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist`.

Comment: They apparently changed the name of the process and `plist` file. I've updated the answer to reflect your findings. Thanks!

Comment: not relevant but the last `sudo su` can be `exit` from the root shell to the user one

Comment: @nkint: It is relevant and you are perfectly right with what you've said. A `sudo su USERNAME` as suggested by @tubedogg can be exited with `exit` again to change back to root user. This might lead to problems if somebody else uses the computer! So whenever using `sudo su root` always(!) use `exit` afterwards to exit properly!

Comment: If you've succeeded, `launchctl list | grep adobe` should return no results.

Comment: For Adobe Acrobat Reader DC the name starts with com.adobe.ARMDCHelper

Answer (score 9):

This sort of file can also be manually deleted from the LaunchAgents or LaunchDaemons folders in the /Library Folder -  with Administrator privileges. This is where the intrusive apps like Adobe often install things--and sometimes apps that are really trustworthy. It's not a bad idea to look through these folders now and then, to see what might have been installed.

There is also a LaunchAgents folder in your User library, where agents sometimes get installed that you can simply trash if especially not wanted.

It is never a good idea, however, to mess with anything in the System Library.

Answer (score 2):

There is an additional thing that may be good to try with Adobe Manager: remove the Adobe Manager application from your Mac. After you do the steps below, you will receive a message that Adobe Manager is not installed in your computer when you start any Adobe software, but it will start normally. Please, find below the steps.

1. Find where Adobe manager is installed. When the Adobe Manager application is running, you can find its path location listing the processes of OS X. The command in terminal is " ps aux | grep Adobe" . After this command you will see all Adobe processes that are running in your Mac.
2. Find the location of processes that have " Adobe Manager " in the line. Probably the files are in the folder called "Utilities" or something similar. If you have Dreamweaver or another Adobe application opened, it will be in the list too but you choose only the ones that have "Adobe Manager" in the line.
3. after it you have deleted the folders with Adobe Manager in the name. you can do it with Finder or in Terminal with the command " sudo rm -R  "

I hope it helps.