# Why does Adobe Reader require an installer?

Tags: pdf, adobe

Does anyone know why Adobe Reader requires a permissioned installer application, rather that simply existing as a self contained macOS application bundle?

What system level configurations is the installer making changes to, and why does Adobe feel they are needed for a simple PDF reader?

Comment: At the very least it registers the [auto-update service](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99865/how-is-adobe-update-notifier-auto-launched-on-mac-os-x/99866#99866). As far as "why," nobody but Adobe can answer that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Acrobat Reader installer not only installs the application itself into `/Applications` but contains a bunch of other packages which need to get installed into other places (e.g. browser plugins). These things can't get installed by just using a simple application bundle (at least not as easily).

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if homebrew (or some other package manager) could script the installer to just extract the reader and ignore the plugins and the updater.

Comment: @patrix By the way - which program did you use to inspect the package? It sound very useful.

Comment: @Rainer The application is called Pacifist

Comment: I've used Pacifist before to extract components and drivers from old OSX images. It's pretty great.